# How to cache database tables in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, database, caching

My app requires repetitive lookup a lot from same tables. Normally it should be design with foreign key to refer from table1 to table2, but there are no foreign keys design(yes db designed poorly).

views look like this:

```
class FileDownloaderSerializer(APIView):

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):

            filename = "All-users.csv"
            f = open(filename, 'w')                
            datas = Userstable.objects.using(dbname).all()                
            serializer = UserSerializer( datas, context={'sector': sector}, many=True)                                        
            df=serializer.data

        df.to_csv(f, index=False, header=False)
        f.close()

        wrapper = FileWrapper(open(filename))
        response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename

        return response
```

this is my serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
        model = Userstable
        fields = _all_
   section=serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   def get_section(self, obj):
        return section.objects.using(dbname.get(pk=obj.sectionid).sectionname

   department =serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   def get_department(self, obj):
        return section.objects.using(dbname).get(pk=obj.deptid).deptname
```

there are lots of table, more than 5 table, here I'm just showing 2 of them. Basically in the csv we need to import representable data. But in the main table, they only stored the id of the data, we need to get the actual representable data from the secondary table, hence the lookups.

from the basics of programming. I understand that python normally cached variables that were being declared when a process runs, so the program doesn't have to go through declarations every time the variable is called. but in my process, the app keeps querying. I monitored the whole SQL using django debug toolbar and got 500 queries, 455 is same queries.

here is the screenshot from django_debug_toolbar

[image: sql queries reported]

So, what is the exact ways of caching table from DB?w

Comment: You can find more anout this topic here: [Django’s cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/cache/#django-s-cache-framework)

Comment: Well according to the screenshoot you shared your problem is not caching the data but you have potentially an `N+1` poor performance. Please clarify me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes, I read something on N+1 ORM and i'm sure it is very related to the problem, how do we normally solve this in lookups?

Comment: I do want  highlight that current databases don't have foreign keys, therefore method such as select_related, and prefetch related cant be use, at least what i understand.